# How to check if an element exists in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a jQuery plugin, it will create a lot of elements in the DOM depending of the number of instances... It's working something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#register-trigger").modal();
});
(function($){
    $.fn.modal = function(a){
        return this.each(function(){
            var el = $(this),
                element = $('<div class="modal close"></div>');
            $("body").prepend(element);
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

But I need to know if the element has been inserted into the page. If not inserted I will use the element in the variable, otherwise I will use the already inserted element on the page... But how to check this?

If I use the following code, it will be said that the element already exists...

```
(function($){
    $.fn.modal = function(a){
        return this.each(function(){
            var el = $(this),
                element = $('<div class="modal close"></div>');
            //This will return 1, same as true
            console.log(element.length);
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

What do I need?

```
if( already inerted into the page ){
    modalOpen();
} else{
    modalCreate();
}
```

I hope you understand. Thank you.

---

EDIT: If element is not appended, i need to return false...

Comment: You already have the answer `element.length`

Comment: If I use the following code, it will be said that the element already exists..., this is where your answer is i.e. using `.length`

Comment: @Satpal look in the second code block, i don't append it yet and it will return true. If not appended, i need to return false...

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Look at the comment above

Comment: @CaioKawasaki, There is no link with second code, Can you post the some more code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
element = $('<div class="modal close"></div>');
console.log(element.length);
```

This will always be 1 because you've just put something into `element`. It doesn't tell you anything about whether the element is in the DOM or not.

Instead you could use something like `$.contains`:

```
if ( $.contains( $( 'body' )[0], element ) {
    // the element has been added
} else {
    // the element has not been added
}
```

**Correction**: my first version had a bug, `$.contains` requires a DOM element as the first argument, not a jQuery object.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/

Comment: I think you got me! This is the idea... However, it's just returning false... What could be?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead...

```
(function($){
    $.fn.modal = function(a){
        return this.each(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            var element = $("div.modal.close");
            if (element.length) {
                // it already exists in the page
            }
            else {
                // it doesn exist.  Create it here
            }
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

It just checked the DOM to see if a matching element already exists.

Comment: Look in the second code block, i don't append it yet and it will return true. If not appended, i need to return false...

Comment: I've modified to what I *think* you're asking.

Comment: @Archer then how could one make a modal if element is a jquery object?

Comment: @Jai if it doesn't exist on the page then you create it, as in the OP's code.

Answer (score -1):

why dont use filter function to see if the element is there , something like

```
function find_this(name) {

                return $('div').filter(function() {
                    return $.trim($(this).text().toLowerCase()) === name;
                })
```

change text to some attribute if you dnt want use the content text as comparaison test..